# MS Access 2010 - Instantiate a child recordset using DAO and get "No current record" error

Tags: vba, ms-access, parent-child, dao, recordset

I'm trying to move data from a table1 in database 1 to table2 in database 2. Table 1 has the same fields as table 2. Table 1 has data and Table 2 don't have.

rsDenuncia is the recordset of table 1 from database 1
regNuevoDenuncia is the recorset of table 2 from database 2

I instantiate a child recordset of rsDenuncia that is named rsODenuncia and it works because
I can retrieve data using msgboxes.

```
Set rsODenuncia = rsDenuncia.Fields("pdfAdjunto").Value
MsgBox "Nombre el archivo: " & rsODenuncia("FileName").Value
MsgBox "Tipo de archivo: " & rsODenuncia.Fields("FileType").Value
MsgBox "Data del archivo: " & rsODenuncia.Fields("FileData").Value
```

But when I try to instantiate the recordset of table 2 (that is an empty table but with same fields as table 1) is gives a error. "No current record"

```
Set regONuevoDenuncia = regNuevoDenuncia.Fields("pdfAdjunto").Value
```

Is there a way to instantiate regONuevoDenuncia without using the Value method so I can add new data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the new parent record with `regNuevoDenuncia.AddNew` before you can open the child recordset for its attachments. The following code is a minimal example:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRecordsWithAttachments()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Dim rsDenuncia As DAO.Recordset2, rsODenuncia As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim regNuevoDenuncia As DAO.Recordset2, regONuevoDenuncia As DAO.Recordset2

    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    cdb.Execute "DELETE FROM NuevoDenuncia", dbFailOnError  ' clear previous test data, if any
    Set rsDenuncia = cdb.OpenRecordset("Denuncia", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set regNuevoDenuncia = cdb.OpenRecordset("NuevoDenuncia", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do Until rsDenuncia.EOF
        regNuevoDenuncia.AddNew
        regNuevoDenuncia!ID = rsDenuncia!ID
        Set rsODenuncia = rsDenuncia.Fields("pdfAdjunto").Value
        Set regONuevoDenuncia = regNuevoDenuncia.Fields("pdfAdjunto").Value
        Do Until rsODenuncia.EOF
            regONuevoDenuncia.AddNew
            regONuevoDenuncia!FileName = rsODenuncia!FileName
            regONuevoDenuncia!FileData = rsODenuncia!FileData
            regONuevoDenuncia.Update
            rsODenuncia.MoveNext
        Loop
        regONuevoDenuncia.Close
        Set regONuevoDenuncia = Nothing
        rsODenuncia.Close
        Set rsODenuncia = Nothing
        regNuevoDenuncia.Update
        rsDenuncia.MoveNext
    Loop
    regNuevoDenuncia.Close
    Set regNuevoDenuncia = Nothing
    rsDenuncia.Close
    Set rsDenuncia = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
    Debug.Print "Terminado."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference that field, in the manner you are,  in the recordset for DB2 until the recordset is populated. Once you add records to DB2, then the error will go away.
Without seeing all your code, I suggest you do something like:

```
If not regNuevoDenuncia.eof then
    Set regONuevoDenuncia = regNuevoDenuncia.Fields("pdfAdjunto").Value
```